# Embed C in PHP to improve speed

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm thinking of writing a PHP extension from C, just to improve the speed. `strpos()` and `preg_match()` etc. are way too slow for my project.

But it struck me, that `strpos()` and `preg_match()` must have been 'originally' written in C or some other primitive language.

So, here my question: Is it meaningful, that I write some extension in C, just in order to improve the computation speed?

Comment: is it really the functions, or your implementation of the functions that are to slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *might* be useful if you can identify a "self-contained" bottleneck. PHP is still a scripting language. There are a lot of lookup operations, some memory operations which can be optimized away in C, maybe a handle/value/memory block from one of the underlying libraries that you could store/use more efficiently in your specific case, and so on and on.

But, make sure that the code block you're touching is worth the effort. I.e. first identify the bottleneck. Run a php profiler (like e.g. xdebug) and then maybe even a C profiler to see where the time is spent in the php runtime. And keep in mind that if you write the extension it's your job to keep it up to date, running and functional (including bug tracking/fixing, quality assurance, ...).

Answer (score 3):

It is really cool that you are interested in writing some extension in PHP.

Please go through the below link to understand more about how Facebook started the HipHop project to increase speed. They achieved this by writing some code in the native language like C instead of PHP.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/

But instead of rewriting some already written ext in PHP, try to write your new one, you will find many articles on writing a new extension in PHP.

The existing extensions are already optimized, so if you want to do some specific work, and have a good algorithm to support it, go for writing your own extension.

Comment: (-1) Your comment regarding hiphop is wrong. C and C++ are not the same (and C++ is not a superset of C!). Also hiphop transforms php into C++ which can be optimized further and then compiled into a whole server. Please correct this so everyone can learn and I can remove my downvote. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

not proofed, but i think, that you can't gain significantly better speed when you just do your own low-level implementation of regular-expressions or string-scanning...
php *is* written in c and highly optimized already...

check your code and improve the flow...

if it's impossible, take a look at "HipHop" from facebook...

Comment: Calling php highly optimized is pretty funny, considering that nearly every php version improves on the performance on the last one, and at the same time very old code in php is still used after years of it being proven slow. Read up on their plan to move to something like hhvm in the future in that regards if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Its not meaningful to write another implementation of `strpos()` or `preg_match()` in C. because PHP has already implemented them in `C`.

rather its meaningful to make your PHP code optimized such that It can use those functions instead of  **abusing** them

But still If you really want to speed things up by providing yet another implementation It might help if and only if its  fast enough. otherwise its just waste of time and labour.

You can have a look on PHP source code and check the current implementation of these function and see if you can really improve or not.